# PHP preg_match_all: extract specific lines

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a problem. I need to get some lines of a page like this:

```
Text text text ...

Porto-Portugal-May-2013
Barcelona-Spain-April-2013

Text text text text text ...

Madrid-Spain-April-2013

Text text text ...
```

I need filter so that only appear the following:

```
Porto-Portugal-May-2013
Barcelona-Spain-April-2013
Madrid-Spain-April-2013
```

(lines with 3 dashes)

It’s possible with preg_match_all or other function?

I use cURL to get page content.

I have tried:

```
$body = " Text text text ...

Porto-Portugal-May-2013
Barcelona-Spain-April-2013

Text text text text text ...

Madrid-Spain-April-2013

Text text text ...";

preg_match_all("/^(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)\/",$body, $match);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($match[1]);$i++)
  {
    echo $match[1][$j].'<br/>';
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with the result you're getting?

Comment: It does not return the result. It's empty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` means "start of string".

Add the `m` modifier to make it mean "start of line" instead.

Then it's easier:

```
preg_match_all("/^(?:[^-\n]+-){3}[^-\n]+$/m",$body,$matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

This should output an array containing each line that matched.

Comment: I get this result:array (size=3)
  0 => string ' Text text text ...

Porto-Portugal-May-2013
' (length=47)
  1 => string 'Barcelona-Spain-April-2013

Text text text text text ...

' (length=61)
  2 => string 'Madrid-Spain-April-2013

Text text text ...' (length=45)

Comment: @ptCoder Ah, of course, it's allowing lines to match in the middle. I've edited the answer, see if that helps?

Comment: Only one more question please: if you replace dashes with # character, what you modify in your preg_match_all code?

Comment: There is not other way?

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you need another way?

Comment: Because I have one separated by dashes, other separeted by #. If I use replace won't work correctly because the page have so many chars. What I need to replace in preg_match_all to work with #? Thank you.

Comment: Right, okay, so you want `[^-#\n]+[-#]` then, instead of `[^-\n]+-`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65712/discussion-between-ptcoder-and-niet-the-dark-absol).

Answer (score 1):

In the case of defined years in the last of your lines, you don't need regex to complete this task, as follows:

```
<?php
$yearsList = array(2013, 2014);
$body = " Text text text ...


Porto-Portugal-May-2013
Barcelona-Spain-April-2013

Text text text text text ...

Madrid-Spain-April-2013

Text text text ...";

$arr = explode("\n",$body);
$res = array();
foreach ($arr as $items){
  $itemArr = explode('-', $items);
    foreach ($itemArr as $item){
      if (in_array($item, $yearsList)) $res[] = $items;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
?>
```

View This DEMO: http://codepad.org/fdhwEJC4